# How do I create a circular gradient in HTML or CSS?

Tags: html

Hey guys I'm wondering if you know of any way on how to create a circular/elliptical gradient that has many colors in HTML or CSS? Or would I have to use an image editing software like Photoshop?

Comment: How is this off topic? The very fact that he is wanting to do this in HTML or CSS makes it very on topic. Just because it's not typically done doesn't make it off topic.

Comment: @Octopus it is offtopic because it's a better question for SO than it is for webmaster.SE

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in SVG or VML, but cross browser compatibility will be an issue. You can look at [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/), a javascript library for doing just this kind of stuff. It should help with the cross-browser issues.

See the [colorpicker](http://raphaeljs.com/picker.html) sample, for example.